# Connecting a program and Arduino with Serial-port

Tags: c, linux, arduino, serial-port, arduino-ide

I'm using `Ubuntu 16` (although i have the same problem on Debian) `Arduino Mega 2560`, 2 versions of `Arduino IDE`: `2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1` and `1.8.9`.

I'm working on a connecting a `C` program with Arduino via COM-port.

For example, I have following code; a PC program sends some text to Arduino, while Arduino receives and prints it.

pc.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

int openPort(char port_name[], speed_t speed)
{
   int F_ID = open(port_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
   fcntl(F_ID, F_SETFL, 0);
    //printf("%s\n", port_name);
    if(F_ID == -1)
    {        
        return -1;
    }
    struct termios options; 
    tcgetattr(F_ID, &options); 

    cfsetispeed(&options, speed);
    cfsetospeed(&options, speed); 

    options.c_cc[VTIME]    = 20;
    options.c_cc[VMIN]     = 0;     

    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; 
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;  

    options.c_lflag = 0;
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    tcsetattr(F_ID, TCSANOW, &options); 

    return F_ID;
}

void closePort(int id)
{
    close(id);
    return;
}

int sendData(int id, unsigned char* buf, int len)
{
    int n = write(id, buf, len);
    if(n == -1)
    {
        char *errmsg = strerror(errno);
        printf("%s\n",errmsg);        
    }
    return n;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int port=openPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", B9600);

    if ( (port) == -1){
        //char *errmsg = strerror(errno);
        printf("Cannot open port: %s\n",strerror(errno));
        return -1;      
    }

    sendData(port, "Hello, Arduino!*", 16);

    closePort(port);
    return 0;
}
```

ard.ino:

```
int stage = 0;
String recv;
char* line;

char* get_line(void)
{ // '*' is a terminal character
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c=='*')
    {
      char* res = (char*)malloc((recv.length()+1)*sizeof(char));
      recv.toCharArray(res, recv.length()+1);
      stage=1;
      recv="";
      return res;
    }
    else { recv += c; }
  } // if (Serial.available() > 0)
}      

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{
  if (stage==0)  
  {
    line = get_line();
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print("Got line: ");
    Serial.println(line);
    stage = 0;
  }
}
```

To check, if my program works fine, I'm using Port Monitor in the IDE.

I have following problem:

I prefer to use `Arduino IDE 1.8.9`, but when I open Port Monitor and run my PC program - nothing works, PC-prog can't access the port and send information (it says `Bad file descriptor`);

while with `Arduino 2:1.0.5+dfsg2-4.1` everything works fine and i can see on Port Monitor:

```
Got line: Hello, Arduino!
```

So I'm asking, what I have to do with `Arduino IDE 1.8.9` parameters or with `/dev/ttyUSB*` for it to work fine with each other?

Comment: I'm still not aware of why this blocking of the `/dev/ttyUSBx` happens, but I can overcome it by running my PC-prog from `sudo`.

Comment: Try: sudo usermod -a -G dialout <your_user>

Comment: @Antonio it is same (`Bad file descriptor` error) after doing this command